# elsarticle + Lineno: numbering abstract's lines

Tags: pdftex, numbering, abstract, elsarticle, lineno

I'm using `elsarticle` class for preparing a manuscript for an Elsevier journal.

However, after I've compiled my document with pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian), the text written in the Abstract section is not numbered, an associated editor complained about this.

The basic manuscript is as follow:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno, hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[1]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Elsevier \LaTeX\ template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}
\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}

%% Group authors per affiliation:
\author{Elsevier\fnref{myfootnote}}
\address{Radarweg 29, Amsterdam}
\fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}

%% or include affiliations in footnotes:
\author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{Elsevier Inc}
\ead[url]{www.elsevier.com}

\author[mysecondaryaddress]{Global Customer Service\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{support@elsevier.com}

\address[mymainaddress]{1600 John F Kennedy Boulevard, Philadelphia}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{360 Park Avenue South, New York}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}



\section{The Elsevier article class}

Here are two sample references: \cite{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get that all the lines within the Abstract section be numbered?

Thanks in advance, Mauricio

Answer (score 3):

Add `\begin{linenumbers}` and `\end{linenumbers}` to the abstract section.

```
\begin{abstract}
\begin{linenumbers}
Lorem Ipsum....
\end{linenumbers}
\end{abstract}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution provided by @ferahfeza worked perfectly !. Thanks